# pronunciation of "was spent"

Tags: pronunciation

**"Was spent"** 
We don't pronounce it as a: /waz spent/

 We do it as a: /was'spent/ (without any gap between was and spent?)

Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: There is a ***tiny*** "gap" separating the final phoneme of ***was*** from the first phoneme of ***spent***. Note that no such gap exists in, for example, *The **wasp entered** through the window*.

Comment: You *cannot* pronounce a consonant and its counterpart *easily* when they come right after each other. Either allow a *tiny pause* (as FF said) between *was* and spent* or skip /z/ of 'was'.

Comment: I find that when I say "was spent", the sequence of three consonants is pronounced with no interruption, with a gradual transition between the voiced 'z', the unvoiced 's', and the 'p'.

Comment:  Same here. This is a situation where you should practise saying the two words separately and slowly decrease the pause/ gap between the words.

Comment: I agree with Jack. There is no pause. The fricative starts voiced, but I'm not convinced that it devoices before it moves to /p/. If I try pronouncing it with a /s/ instead of a /z/ in "was", it certainly comes out different; but if I try saying "was zpent" (without making it "was zbent"), I can't detect any difference from "was spent" except by pausing before the /p/

Comment: Thank you guys, I just little confused but I think I got it from answer of @DecapitatedSoul

Comment: @WorldLover, Second comment or fourth?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul This one: You cannot pronounce a consonant and its counterpart easily when they come right after each other. Either allow a tiny pause (as FF said) between was and spent* or skip /z/ of 'was'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Was spent" We don't pronounce it as a: /waz spent/
>   We do it as a: /was'spent/ (without any gap between was and spent?)
>   Did I understand it correctly?

'Was' ends with **/z/** (voiced sound) and 'spent' starts with **/s/** (voiceless sound). **/s/** and **/z/** are *counterparts* of each other i.e. **/s/** is the *voiceless counterpart* of **/z/** sound and **/z/** is the *voiced counterpart* of **/s/** sound.
It means they are [articulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulatory_phonetics) from the same place (the alveolar ridge) and have the same *manner of articulation* ([sibilants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant)). The difference between /z/ and /s/ sound is the vibration of vocal folds.

*If you feel behind your top teeth with your tongue, you should be able to feel a little shelf-like part right there behind your top teeth. 
That little shelf-like bit behind your teeth is your alveolar ridge.*

As they are articulated from the same place and have the same manner of articulation, you cannot pronounce both of them easily when one comes right after another.

Pronounce *bits*, you will be able to pronounce the /ts/ easily because /t/ and /s/ have different manner of articulation.

Now pronounce *was spent* (pronounce 'z' and 's' respectively), you will not be able to pronounce /zs/ easily because /z/ and /s/ have the same manner of articulation.

There are two ways to pronounce them:

1. Skip /z/ sound in 'was' and link 'wa' to /s/ sound of 'spent' -> *wasspent*
2. Allow a small pause between 'was' and 'spent' -> /wɒz/ (tiny pause) /spent/.

(If you don't want to allow a small pause, then skip the preceding sound /z/, it's almost imperceptible)

(I myself pronounce both /z/ and /s/ sounds. It happens naturally. As I said in my comment, 'This is a situation where you should practise saying the two words separately and slowly decrease the pause/ gap between the words'.)